# Calling `this.setState()` breaks flow type checking on a prop in componentWillReceiveProps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype, setstate

I am getting a flow error on a prop that I know is a string when I call `this.setState()` right before it. If I move the `setState()` call after the line that uses the prop, the error goes away. The error I'm getting is:

> null
>
> This type is incompatible with the expected param type of string
>
> undefined
>
> This type is incompatible with the expected param type of string

Both errors occur on the same line of code.

Here is a stripped down version of the component. See the implementation of `componentWillReceiveProps`:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import apiRequest from "../../services/apiRequest";

type PropsT = {
  endpoint: ?string,
};

export default class ApiLoader extends Component {
  props: PropsT

  static defaultProps = { endpoint: null }
  state = { isFetching: true }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps: PropsT) {
    if (!nextProps.endpoint) return;

    this.setState({ isFetching: true });
    this.fetch(nextProps.endpoint);       // FLOW ERROR HERE
  }

  fetch(endpoint: string) {
    apiRequest.get(endpoint)
      .then(() => this.setState({ isFetching: false }));
  }

  render(): React.Element<*> {
    return <div>Whatever.</div>;
  }
}
```

Simply switching the order of those final two lines in `componentWillReceiveProps` fixes it:

```
this.fetch(nextProps.endpoint);      // NO ERROR!
this.setState({ isFetching: true });
```

Is this just a bug in Flow, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to a type refinement invalidation: https://flow.org/en/docs/lang/refinements/#toc-refinement-invalidations

Pull out `endpoint` into its own variable and you should be good to go.

Comment: Yes, that works. In an ideal world, however, flow should be able to tell that in my implementation, `setState()` won't modify the value of the prop, correct? Or is there truly something I'm missing about the side effects that `setState` might have? I ask partly because I'm feeling a bit frustrated by how much I have to modify my coding style so that flow knows what's going on when I think it should be able to figure stuff out without the additional help :)

Comment: You are right that this analysis is theoretically possible, and I believe that you are also right that in this case, calling `setState` is safe. However, for performance reasons, Flow can only look at the type (not the implementation) of another function while it is performing typechecking. So, in order for Flow to avoid throwing out refinements, you would have to express purity in the type. `setState` isn't strictly pure, so you would also have to somehow express in the type which things it may modify. Clearly this would quickly become complicated and confusing.

Comment: By the way, I understand your frustration. Type systems put significant constraints on what you can do. Flow is very expressive as type systems go, but if you are not used to using one it could certainly be irritating. I tolerate the downsides because I believe there are significant upsides, but that doesn't mean the downsides don't exist.