# Problem narrowing multiple properties with flow type

Tags: flowtype

i'm wondering why the following code isn't valid in flow.

[Flowtyped try link](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgBiccYAvGAN6phgBGAhgE4BcYAzhkwJYB2A5qgC+6bPjAARBhgbkqNMAwDGAWzxteAVxgwwAHyphecACZ52bYnADaAXTBCANArp4ZG7boOUjp85ZI7B2F0KE1eJQxuOF5FAAoTaQY2KRk9LR0ASnlabigwOIVaAEJEmX09IrBSpIA6ZTUKqpqZetU8WuMzdibaErKGWtdyvUq+6oGht0Gu8wVs6nGmN00mXgURWgUlGM4wKG4YDDxlkwBBdoCbewpJho7Z9lqDo5O4gCESGDwGXkyAbm2uww+0Ox1O72mVyCtzqwxmfieL3BHy+Pz+-zAwGAYAAPABafFgAD8pJCqDCESiMXoCSSKSS6U8CwUeQKLQY2WWGFW61y+TiHLaai5KzWrIFQvunURop54qBvD2yJOeHOlyIgRuYDu7Rl3WeYLenzg31+AIUEvZk3hct5YCtgpt0315jt4q2tB2SpBKohUM11zkztaj0NryYqNN6ItIgp4Ui0ViSjp7kkjIyMBZ-OtSXdfLAbKddXu+cdUr1jzLOeLrVtYG59vLIYR3TLiuVRtOFzU0O1urUrqRXajZoxnrA3s7EbVkLTVhhOrhLrDftHMcBQiAA)

```js
/* @flow */

type Foo = {
  bar: string
}

type Data = {
  acme: null | { nodes: Foo[] },
  beta: null | { nodes: Foo[] }
}

function a(data: Data|null) {
  if (
    !data ||
    !data.acme ||
    !data.acme.nodes ||
    !data.beta ||
    !data.beta.nodes
  ) {
    return
  }

  const filteredAcme: Foo[] = data.acme.nodes.filter(Boolean);
  const filteredBeta: Foo[] = data.beta.nodes.filter(Boolean); // <-- error on this line
  // Cannot get `data.beta.nodes` because property `nodes` is missing in null [1].
}
```

it seems like the if statement should narrow the types so that we know beta.nodes are present.

Comment: This is due to refinement invalidations. One way around this is to pull the data you'd like to refine out into local variables (use `const`). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43403154/calling-this-setstate-breaks-flow-type-checking-on-a-prop-in-componentwillre/43403223#43403223

Comment: simplified example: https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVUCuA7AxgFwEs5sxcSBnTAWwFMAnACgDcBDGALjAv3sOwDmASjABvAL4YcBYqQAmcAHJx8AC34DGIieix4iJMLQAeragAcYtACyMocOF1EAjVvS4B+Hn0HjtqMDBCKDA7BwA6V3p-QMCFZTUNLQBuANjybCo6Jns4SLchZMDgYCN6ejh6AEI0yXEgA

Answer (score 1):

It should, but current version of flow poorly detect presents checked on the object properties, creating local variables should help. Like the following:

[Check in Flow Try](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgBiccYAvGAN6phgBGAhgE4BcYAzhkwJYB2A5qgC+6bPjAARBhgbkqNMAwDGAWzxteAVxgwwAHyphecACZ52bYnADaAXTBCANArp4ZG7boOUjp85ZI7B2F0KE1eJQxuOF5FAAoTaQY2KRk9LR0ASnlabigwOIBCRJlspjdNJl4FBSUYzipXGUdFVTwhORKGAG4FPILCptk9A0G3BgA6YzN2fVHlNTmwQoW8Kb92MoqqsF7a+owwKG4YDDxykwBBNoCbewpV9ZmJ49PzuIAhEhg8Bl5M3q0Oq8BqvM4XD7jW5BChDJ7mF4ncGfb6-f7dMDAYBgAA8AFo8WAAPwkkKoMIRKIxegJJIpJLpTzZai5fJFLpbDCVaqsgZdCarTncvps4pJAVteGbMDlLlVdBAg5HJHnPBXG5EQL3MD8x7TBFg95fOA-P4Amq89nioZCnYivnW8ZS208sD7EGHQ0QqGau6dR0yKWIt5MFEmtHmkTk8KRaKxJS09ySBkZGDM+1W0oy7au-qZyaC7Ny3Oi3WS-XS2XCxUexrjDoULqAsB5sZZqt2y1tyYVl0KsDA0Eqi7XNTQ7VltRBr1h03o2juochtWQpNWGH0J0V4PI41zyNAA)

```js
/* @flow */

type Foo = {
  bar: string
}

type Data = {
  acme: null | { nodes: Foo[] },
  beta: null | { nodes: Foo[] }
}

function a(data: Data|null) {
  if (!data) return

  const {beta, acme} = data;
  if (!beta || !beta.nodes || !acme || !acme.nodes) return ;

  const filteredAcme: Foo[] = acme.nodes.filter(Boolean);
  const filteredBeta: Foo[] = beta.nodes.filter(Boolean); // <-- ???
}

function b(data: Data|null) {
  if (!data) return
  if (!data.acme) return
  if (!data.acme.nodes) return

  const filteredAcme: Foo[] = data.acme.nodes.filter(Boolean);

  if (!data.beta) return 
  if (!data.beta.nodes) return

  const filteredBeta: Foo[] = data.beta.nodes.filter(Boolean);
}

function c(data: Data|null) {
  if (!data) return
  if (!data.acme) return
  if (!data.acme.nodes) return
  const {beta} = data;
  if (!beta) return 
  if (!beta.nodes) return

  const filteredAcme: Foo[] = data.acme.nodes.filter(Boolean);  
  const filteredBeta: Foo[] = beta.nodes.filter(Boolean);
}
```

Comment: What if the type is a bit more complex? Your solution seems to fail with something like this: `function a(data: Data|null|Node)`, I know it does not make any sense, but how make flow happy here